# Google cloud endpoints vs. endpoints realized with android studio

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

What is the difference between the endpoints app engine, realized with android Studio (Cloud module), and the google cloud endpoints, shown in the google cloud console menu point 'Endpoints' under 'Tools'?

thank you for answering quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Version 2.0, Cloud Endpoints is more than just the Endpoints v1.0, which are a set "tools, libraries and capabilities that allow you to generate APIs and client libraries from an App Engine application". Endpoints 1.0 = "the endpoints app engine, realized with android Studio" in your question.

Version 2.0 allows to "Develop, deploy and manage APIs on **any** Google Cloud Platform backend", as detailed in the doc and in the Cloud Console Help for the "Endpoints" menu item:

> **Use Endpoints to manage APIs**
>
> Google Cloud Platform supports using Cloud Endpoints to manage an API running in Google Compute Engine, Google Container Engine, or App Engine Flexible Environment. Google Cloud Endpoints let you manage and control access to your APIs. You can keep APIs private or share them with partners, and you can monitor API usage.
>
> **Endpoints overview**
>
> For a general overview of using Endpoints to manage your APIs, see What is Cloud Endpoints. This article describes what you can do with Endpoints and links to more detailed information.
>
> **Viewing API metrics in the console**
>
> Endpoints tracks certain usage metrics for activity and performance, and makes these available for viewing in various graphs in the Cloud Platform Console. For a description of what these graphs contain, see Viewing API Metrics in the Google Cloud Platform documentation.
>
> **Share your API with developers**
>
> Google Cloud Endpoints APIs are private by default, so only members of the project who manage the API can see it. To make your API available to other developers:
>
> 1. Go to the Cloud Platform Console
> 2. From the projects list, select a project.
> 3. Open the console left side menu and select Endpoints.
> 4. Select your API. Click Share API.
> 5. To add a user or Google Group email address, click Add developers.

The Endpoints v1.0 were renamed to "Cloud Endpoints Frameworks for App Engine", see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/

You can also have a look at the following blog posts from the GCP blog:

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/09/manage-your-APIs-with-Google-Cloud-Endpoints.html

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/02/Google-Cloud-Endpoints-now-GA-a-fast-scalable-API-gateway.html

Finally, note that "Android Studio support for Cloud Endpoints 1.0" is not currently supported for version 2.0. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/migrating

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanations. I now have a good basis for my further proceed. I stay for this project with connection to cloud sql with endpoints 1.0.